# unable to filter or search the data in different languages in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, multilingual, django-filter, django-multilingual

I have posted data(ex:title field) in different languages, when i try to filter the data in get request it is giving empty result

**GET /rails:**
My get request result is :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "channel",
        "filter": [
            1
        ],
        "data": [
            1
        ],
        "status": 0,
        "rows": 0,
        "title": "string"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "appgg",
        "filter": [
            2
        ],
        "data": [
            2
        ],
        "status": 1,
        "rows": 2,
        "title": "ಚಲನಚಿತ್ರ"
    }
]
```

**GET /rails?title=string**
it is giving proper result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "channel",
        "filter": [
            1
        ],
        "data": [
            1
        ],
        "status": 0,
        "rows": 0,
        "title": "string"
    }
]
```

when i try to filter title data other than english i am getting empty result

**GET /rails?title=ಚಲನಚಿತ್ರ:**

expected result :

```
[


    {
            "id": 2,
            "type": "appgg",
            "filter": [
                2
            ],
            "data": [
                2
            ],
            "status": 1,
            "rows": 2,
            "title": "ಚಲನಚಿತ್ರ"
        }
]
```

Actual result:

```
[]
```

when I try to print request params in my django views like below:

```
title = self.request.query_params.getlist('title',None)
print(title)
```

I am getting the following log:

```
title filter �²¨�¿¤Í°
```

Django is unable to identify the language I am passing, How can I add multi-language support in Django?

Thanks

Comment: does your filter work with normal English?

Comment: yes, it is giving the proper result , check above once i have added the result

Comment: Check your client, using a browser, here's what I get from the query_params: ['ಚಲನಚಿತ್ರ']

Comment: In browser it is working but in postman it is giving [] empty result